# Can't run applications made with java jdk12

Tags: windows-10, java

I used to write my applications with jdk 8. I upgraded to jdk 12 but my jre seems to be still on 1.8. I tried to find the official download site for jre 12, but it always redirects to the 1.8. After that I didn't really care for JDK 12 and tried to download the old jdk 8, but the site asks me to register at Oracle as soon as I try to download. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Is it impossible to use java for free for private uses? Shall I think about switching to openJDK? How to solve this?

Here is the cmd output. The application was written with JDK 12.

```
C:\Users\whoami\Desktop>java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\whoami\Desktop>java -jar exd.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: docxxxenc/Startup has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not yet a JRE for version 12, unlike previous version, now the JDK will include everything you need to be able to run and compiler your code. The reason you cannot run it I would guess it has to do with your system variables, you need to make sure you have your environemnt variables pointed to the correct path like you normally would:

**JAVA_HOME** = (your jdk path)
     and
**PATH** = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. I uninstalled everything besides jdk 12 and set javahome and path. Wroked!